# How to control font style, color, and size inside a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` in Java Swing.  I need to set the font size, color and style.  How can I implement that in `JTable`?

Comment: JTable already has "default" style. I guess you want to set new style.

Comment: For individual cells or the whole table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

why set TableRenderer for basic setting in the [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), more --> [JTable#setWhatever](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowHeight%28int%29)

[image]

EDIT (ballast removed) code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableExample {

    public TableExample() {
        Object[][] data1 = new Object[50][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
            data1[i][0] = "Company # " + (i + 1);
            for (int j = 1; j < data1[i].length; j++) {
                data1[i][j] = "" + (i + 1) + ", " + j;
            }
        }
        String[] headers = {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3", "Col 4", "Col 5"};
        DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel(data1, headers);
        final JTable jTable1 = new JTable(model1);
        jTable1.setBackground(Color.orange);
        jTable1.setForeground(Color.blue);
        jTable1.setRowHeight(24);
        jTable1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        jTable1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        final JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane();
        sp1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        sp1.setViewportView(jTable1);
        final JTable jTable2 = new JTable(model1);
        jTable2.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        final JScrollPane sp2 = new JScrollPane();
        sp2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        sp2.setViewportView(jTable2);
        final JTable jTable3 = new TableBackroundPaint0(data1, headers);
        jTable3.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jTable3.setModel(model1);
        final JScrollPane sp3 = new JScrollPane();
        sp3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        sp3.setViewportView(jTable3);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0, 10, 10));
        panel1.add(sp1);
        panel1.add(sp2);
        panel1.add(sp3);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("tableSelection");
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableExample te = new TableExample();
            }
        });
    }
}

class TableBackroundPaint0 extends JTable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    TableBackroundPaint0(Object[][] data, Object[] head) {
        super(data, head);
        setOpaque(false);
        ((JComponent) getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)).setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Color background = new Color(168, 210, 241);
        Color controlColor = new Color(230, 240, 230);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Paint oldPaint = g2.getPaint();
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, background, width, 0, controlColor));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g2.setPaint(oldPaint);
        for (int row : getSelectedRows()) {
            Rectangle start = getCellRect(row, 0, true);
            Rectangle end = getCellRect(row, getColumnCount() - 1, true);
            g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(start.x, 0, controlColor, (int) ((end.x + end.width - start.x) * 1.25), 0, Color.orange));
            g2.fillRect(start.x, start.y, end.x + end.width - start.x, start.height);
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for random code snippets recycled ;-) Or what have the parts about custom selection and background image to do with the question? As @camickr recently reminded you: code in answers should be as focused to the problem as code in questions (or sscce, to please Andrew :)

Comment: @kleopatra accepted, but then is contraproductive asking Andrew for SSCCE, his answer in all respects meet the standards for quality answers that there were clear your comment

Comment: ahh .. that's a misunderstanding, I had no intention of asking @Andrew Thompson for example code, it's a joke between the two of us, me never remembering the exact letters of the acronym :-) If you accept  your examples being overly verbose and not to the point: please feel free to edit your answer :-)

Comment: @kleopatra please see my edit, then now all de/constructive comments are welcome, why not ...

Comment: @kleopatra for example last his comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178347/how-to-import-an-image-in-menu-bar

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thanks, but some your creatures are unforgettable, especially if you starts an answer with Dear Playboy ... (OTN)

Comment: Thank you thank you very much mKorbel. It was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 6):

Set a custom [TableCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html).  See [How to Use Tables - Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) in the Java Tutorial for more details.