# How to set the color of a Font?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I have a JList and inside that list, I want to change the color of the font of the following words.

Someone said that I have to use CellRenderer but I'm not yet familiar with that.

Now, my problem is how can I setup this renderer to change the color of the Font?

Any idea about this matter?

Thanks...

Comment: suggest to always have a tab open with http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html - and quickly read the how-to-use xx chapter (with xx being the component you don't know yet :-)

Comment: is it possible to make two different colors in one JLabel inside a list?

Comment: I have a list of words in my Jlist and beside of every words are their definitions. I want that the font of the words are having a different colors than their definition. My question is that, Is it possible to have a two different colors in one Jlist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html), it might just have what you need (the example at the top). Basically you just return a component (like a JLabel) with a configured font color.

Edit: since you want to have the words in a different color than their definitions, here two possibilities how that can be done with the list cell renderer:

1. Return a JPanel that contains 2 JLabels, one with the word and one with the definitions. Both labels can have different foreground colors.
2. JLabel supports HTML (like other Swing components do), so you might just set the text of the label as `<html><font color=red>your word</font> - your definitions</html>`. Note that the default foreground color should then be the one for the definitions, alternatively you can wrap the definitions with a `<font>` tag as well. Have a look at this [Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

Comment: I have a list of words in my Jlist and beside of every words are their definitions. I want that the font of the words are having a different colors than their definition. My question is that, Is it possible to have a two different colors in one Jlist?

Comment: @Mikel yes, this is possible. I'll add two possibilities.

Answer (score 6):

For `JLabel` components try:

```
    new DefaultListCellRenderer(){
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent( JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus ) { 
            JLabel label = (JLabel)super.getListCellRendererComponent( list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus );
            label.setForeground( Color.RED );
            return label;
        }  
    };
```

Comment: I have a list of words in my Jlist and beside of every words are their definitions. I want that the font of the words are having a different colors than their definition. My question is that, Is it possible to have a two different colors in one Jlist?

Answer (score 2):

consider ...., that would be better using a `JTable` with one `TableColumn` and without `TableHeader` as the `JList`, demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901153/expand-jlist-row-height-depending-on-content/6902589#6902589), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212114/how-to-control-font-style-color-and-size-inside-a-jtable/7213123#7213123), by using [prepareRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900628/refreshing-background-color-for-a-row-in-jtable/6901508#6901508), because [JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) has lots of restriction/missed methods as [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: - 1 for over-complicating ;-) The question was clearly about JList and the way to configure it's cell appearance is a .. well ... custom renderer implemenatation.

Comment: and I enjoyed that just @Andrew Thompson gets it from you, today:-)