# System Font with default built-in fonts for unsupported characters

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt

I'm using the `Segoe UI` system font on Windows for `JLabel`. `Segoe UI` does not support CJK characters, but instead of defaulting to something (e.g. `Font.DIALOG`) for those characters, it'll just display placeholders.

I would like to use `Segoe UI` on Windows because it looks better for Latin characters, but I don't want to lose support for displaying CJK characters altogether.

Is there a way to combine fonts? Prefer `Segoe UI` for Latin characters, but default to `Font.DIALOG` (or any other system default) to render readable characters at the very least.

e.g.

```
Font font = new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 12);
label.setFont(font);
```

[image: CJK characters are not rendered]

Comment: You can check whether a font supports a character and switch fonts if it doesn't. But not easy to make a label implementation with multiple fonts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557597/gui-how-can-i-find-out-if-certain-unicode-characters-are-supported

Comment: One practical solution would be to [find all the available fonts](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/swing-faq-list-fonts-current-platform/) on your system and pick a more complete font to use.  Use the example code in the link, but add Latin characters to the output.

Comment: Could you please add an example string with your special characters so we can test possible solutions?

Comment: Sure. Try with "日本" and "한국".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `StyleContext#getFont` which will call the internal api `FontUtilities#getCompositeFontUIResource(Font)`. This function will create a composite font which will use a fallback font for unsupported characters.

Note that you don't have control over which font will be used as a fallback.

Because the returned font is an `UIResource` we need to wrap it to avoid it being overwritten by the LookAndFeel. The custom `NonUIResourceFont` class is necessary because the constructor of `Font` which takes another `Font` is protected.

```java
public static Font createFont(final String family, final int style, final int size) {
    return new NonUIResourceFont(StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getFont(family, style, size));
}

public static class NonUIResourceFont extends Font {

    public NonUIResourceFont(final Font font) {
        super(font);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the idea suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7344277/11948496) answer you can use a `JLabel`s ability to display html to switch your font whenever needed:

```
public static String transformText(String text) {
    Font defaultFont = new JLabel().getFont();
    Font segoe = new Font("Segoe UI", defaultFont.getStyle(), defaultFont.getSize());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
        "<html><span style=\"font-family: " + defaultFont.getFamily() + "\">");
    boolean inDefaultFont = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char current = text.charAt(i);
        if (segoe.canDisplay(current) ^ inDefaultFont) {
            // font already correct
            sb.append(current);
        } else {
            // switch font
            sb.append("</span><span style=\"font-family: "
                + (inDefaultFont ? segoe.getFamily() : defaultFont.getFamily())
                + "\">" + current);
            inDefaultFont = !inDefaultFont;
        }
    }
    sb.append("</span></html>");

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Which results from the test input `日本 한국 01 abc` to the output `<html><span style="font-family: Dialog">日本</span><span style="font-family: Segoe UI"> </span><span style="font-family: Dialog">한국</span><span style="font-family: Segoe UI"> 01 abc</span></html>` which gets displayed as desired in a `JLabel`.